# Change Jenkins URL (github auth)

Tags: authentication, jenkins, url, github-api

We had Jenkins configured on a remote server using github credentials at jenkins.A.com . The URLs were changed before Jenkins was updated so the server is now accessed at jenkins.B.com, and now after we visit and try github credentials, I am bounced back to `http://jenkins.A.com/securityRealm/finishLogin?code=ZYX&state=XYZ` -- in otherwords, somewhere `jenkins.A.com` is saved and that's what I need to change to `jenkins.B.com` . Is there a config file or some other headless way I can do this, given that I cannot log in to Jenkins via browser?

Answer (score 1):

The fix was not in Jenkins, but in Github. My problem was actually that the callback address on my github oath application. The answer was to edit the application and make sure the callback address was the new address, as per https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/managing-oauth-apps

With this corrected I just needed to make sure my Apache config was correct and then everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and set the global Git configuration (global to the same account Jenkins is running) with [`insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf):

```
git config --global url."http://jenkins.B.com".insteadOf http://jenkins.A.com
```

That way, Git would consider B only, wherever A is still used.

Comment: You think this is a git problem, not a Jenkins one? I didn't think Jenkins took information about its own url from git

Comment: @WebdevTory I think Jenkins is using Git. And if it is using Git, an `url.insteadOf` directive isa good way to force Jenkins to use Git as you need it to.

Comment: Ok. In that case, where should I find its .git folder (on Linux)?

Comment: @WebdevTory I am talking about a global Git config, not a .git repository: ~/.gitconfig, probably on the Jenkins main server (master). Check which user Jenkins is running with. If there is no global Git config, create it (with the right user, meaning the one used by Jenkins) with `git config --global ...` (mentioned in the answer)

Comment: ``` git config --global url."http://jenkins.B.com".insteadOf http://jenkins.A.com
git config --show-origin --get-all url
# error: key does not contain a section: url ```

Comment: Results in file:/var/lib/jenkins/.gitconfig , which contains nothing but the line added by the earlier command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228590/discussion-between-vonc-and-webdev-tory).